# Google maps - url with lat & lon returns "We could not find *lat*, *lon*"

Tags: google-maps

I have website that creates url with lat and lon values like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=45.50459,-73.56363
```

This has worked as expected for couple of years eg returns Google Map with pin on the location of the lat and lon, but recently I am occasionally getting the following result:

```
We could not find 45.52705,-73.61622
Make sure your search is spelled correctly. Try adding a city, state, or zip code.
```

The Google Map page screenshot with this result is below.

If I put my cursor into search box and hit enter with the lat and lon, it successfully returns expected results eg map with pin on lat and lon.

This appears to be occasional and random.  A url with specific lat and lon may work, but then when tried a second time, it returns the results below.

Any ideas what is happening here?

To be clear I am not looking for alternate url solutions, but am looking for insight into why my url solution, which does work, but occasionally and randomly returns the "We could not find *lat*, *lon*" page. As far as I can tell, my url solution is acceptable.

Is this a Google time out or some other rate limiting effect?

[image]

Comment: To the downvoter: yes there are many other questions and answers related to this. While there are multiple seemingly acceptable url solutions including mine, my question is why does my url solution work sometimes and not others? This is a very specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Google limits the use of their APIs. That alone can account for what you perceive as inconsistent behavior. Add in that they use multiple datacenters to load balance that might have different sensitivities to enforce limits and you're out of luck to figure it all out yourself.

The solution is to follow the "rules".

You need to apply for an API key and based on usage you might even have to send them money to do this reverse geocoding.

References:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits

Comment: My usage is a very small fraction of the Standard API usage limits (2,500 free requests per day, 10 requests per second).

Answer (score -1):

Google Maps (http://maps.google.com) has changed.  They changed their URL query scheme.  It wasn't documented (by them at least).  If you want a consistent result, one option would be to use the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/).

Comment: Thanks yes I do wish a consistent result but why is another url query scheme acceptable only sometimes? Is this Google's prompt to change?